# Python: how to create a positive test for procedures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, static-methods, assert, procedure

I have a class with some `@staticmethod`'s that are procedures, thus they do not return anything / their return type is `None`.

If they fail during their execution, they throw an `Exception`.

I want to `unittest` this class, but I am struggling with designing positive tests.

For negative tests this task is easy:

```
assertRaises(ValueError, my_static_method(*args))
assertRaises(MyCustomException, my_static_method(*args))
```

...but how do I create positive tests? Should I redesign my procedures to always return `True` after execution, so that I can use `assertTrue` on them?

Comment: Just call the function without any assertions. If it rasises an exception, the test will fail.

Comment: So if the procedure _doesn't_ raise an exception, it succeeded?  Then just call the procedure _without_ a try/catch wrapper.

Comment: Yes; if the procedure does *not* raise an exception, it succeeded. If an exception is raised, it is caught by other classes that use the procedures. Thus, any exception would be thrown at the unittest method if something bad happens.

Comment: How about `assertIsNone`? Like you said yourself, `None` is what a "procedure" should return. So to me it seems `assertIsNone` would check exactly the right thing.

Comment: Oh yeah...thanks! Sometimes I really miss the forest for the trees :/

Comment: A procedure has a side effect, or there is no point in calling it. Test that the side effect occurs.

Comment: list.sort is tested by seeing whether it actually sorts various test lists. list.reverse is tested by seeing whether it actually reverses various test lists. list.pop is tested by seeing whether it returns the last item (if there is one) and otherwise leave the list alone.  What is your procedure supposed to do?  Either post the code or describe its action.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy My question was/is rather generic, since I have various procedures to test, but to give an example: one procedure checks a temporary directory for unused (like "already processed") files and deletes them, if there are any. I am now testing with `assertIsNone` to check that the procedure is not throwing any exception if called normally (with or without files left for deletion) and I have written a second test method for the side effects: it creates some temp files and then checks if the procedure cleans all of them correctly.

Comment: That sounds exactly right.  You could have the function return True if it did anything, False if not, but that is a secondary issue.

Comment: If I were you, I'd consider posting on [codereview.stackexchange.com](//codereview.stackexchange.com/) asking for a way to make your code easier to test. Note: you'll need to post your actual code there (a couple of lines, a toy example or an [mcve] **won't** suffice). Note#2: be prepared to get improvement suggestions for all aspects of your code, not just the testability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the actual code it is hard to guess, however I will make some assumptions:

1. The logic in the static methods is deterministic.
2. After doing some calculation on the input value there is a result
   and some operation is done with this result.
3. python3.4 (mock has evolved and moved over the last few versions)

In order to test code one has to check that at least in the end it produces the expected results. If there is no return value then the result is usually stored or send somewhere. In this case we can check that the method that stores or sends the result is called with the expected arguments.

This can be done with the tools available in the `mock` package that has become part of the `unittest` package.

e.g. the following static method in `my_package/my_module.py`:

```
import uuid

class MyClass:

    @staticmethod
    def my_procedure(value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            prefix = 'string'
        else:
            prefix = 'other'

        with open('/tmp/%s_%s' % (prefix, uuid.uuid4()), 'w') as f:
            f.write(value)
```

In the unit test I will check the following:

1. `open` has been called.
2. The expected file name has been calculated.
3. `open`has been called in `write` mode.
4. The `write()` method of the file handle has been called with the expected argument.

Unittest:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_package.my_module import MyClass


class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('my_package.my_module.open', create=True)
    def test_my_procedure(self, open_mock):
        write_mock = open_mock.return_value.write
        MyClass.my_procedure('test')
        self.assertTrue(open_mock.call_count, 1)
        file_name, mode = open_mock.call_args[0]
        self.assertTrue(file_name.startswith('/tmp/string_'))
        self.assertEqual(mode, 'w')
        self.assertTrue(write_mock.called_once_with('test'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your methods do something, then I'm sure there should be a logic there. Let's consider this dummy example:

```
cool = None

def my_static_method(something):
    try:
       cool = int(something)
    except ValueError:
       # logs here
```

for negative test we have:

```
assertRaises(ValueError, my_static_method(*args))
```

and for possitive test we can check cool:

```
assertIsNotNone(cool)
```

So you're checking if invoking `my_static_method` affects on `cool`.